# Mortgage Calculator Swift

Tags: swift

I am a beginner with Xcode and Swift. Below is my formula for the mortgage calculator. It is working correct in Playground but when I transfer  it to the ViewController tab that is when Xcode is giving me a bunch of errors. Can someone please help?

```
let r: Double = interestRate / 1200
let n: Double = years * 12
let p: Double = pow(1 + r, n)


let monthPay = loan * r * p / (p - 1)
print(monthPay)
```

So in my View Controller
valueA is Loan Amount
valueB is Number of Payments
valueC is Interest Rate

underneath that you will have a calculate button that will print the results underneath in a label currently named results. It may be that when i rename everything to the values is when the issues occur.

ViewController Code

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var valueA: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueB: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueC: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var results: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        let a = Int(valueA.text!)
        let b = Int(valueB.text!)
        let c = Int(valueC.text!)
        let answer = a! * c! * pow(1 + c!, b!) / (pow(1 + c!, b!))
        results.text = "$\(answer)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are converting your textfield values to integers and trying to multiply them by the result of pow's method which returns a Double. Note that if the user enters an invalid value your app will crash if you force unwrap the result. Yo can use nil coalescing operator `??` to provide a default value `.zero` in case of failure. Try like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var valueA: UITextField!  // loan amount
    @IBOutlet weak var valueB: UITextField!  // Number of Payments
    @IBOutlet weak var valueC: UITextField!  // Interest Rate
    @IBOutlet weak var results: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        let loanAmount = Double(valueA.text!) ?? .zero
        let numberOfPayments = Double(valueB.text!) ?? .zero
        let interestRate = Double(valueC.text!) ?? .zero
        let rate = interestRate / 100 / 12
        let answer = loanAmount * rate / (1 - pow(1 + rate, -numberOfPayments))
        results.text = Formatter.currency.string(for: answer)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Formatter {
    static let currency: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Would this go under the IBAction func button as well? 

    let r: Double = interestRate / 1200
    let n: Double = years * 12
   let Pow: Double = pow(1 + r, n)

I also assume for me it would be 
    let c: Double = interest rate / 1200
    let b: Double = years * 12
    let Pow: Double = pow(1 + c, b)

Comment: @DylanWilliams when coding in Swift you should always name your variables with descriptive names. Avoid as much as possible names such as a, b, c unless you are naming coordinates like x, y

Comment: r would be interest rate formula to help with mortgage, n would be payment formula, p would be the Pow func

Comment: I would assume this is not the best way to work with a mortgage formula in swift

Comment: Personally I would just use `0` instead of `.zero`.